# event listener for numeric string in any input or textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to make an greasemonkey script/chrome extension so when I enter the first four numbers of my credit card, it opens a new tab with porn in it to distract me instead. Help me help us all save money.

Totally serious by the way - can this be done?

Comment: Since CC numbers are typically only on text input fields, I was toying with `onkeydown` and trying to add an event listener for it but I'm terrible with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
$(function() {
    $("html").on("keyup", "input", function() {
        if(/^\d{4}$/.test(this.value)) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

It binds a `keyup` listener to all input fields (including dynamically-created fields) which checks the field for values with exactly four digits.

Comment: getting a syntax error, not sure why. (unpexted } but it looks right)

Comment: I forgot a closing parens on the `on` function; edited.  Also, just so you know, `on` requires jQuery 1.7 or later.